# How to scrape multiple pages on Yahoo Finance with Beautiful Soup BS4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, data-mining

I am new to Python and trying to get some financial data from Yahoo Finance using BS4.
With a single page the script works perfectly fine. However, now I am trying to scrape multiple pages at once but somehow the for `url in urls:` loop does not work as expected. It will just scrape the data from the last url.

Anyone an idea how to solve that?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import json
import ast
import os
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
import datetime 

# For ignoring SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

# Input from the user
urls = ['https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ALV.DE?p=ALV.DE&.tsrc=fin-srch', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SAP?p=SAP&.tsrc=fin-srch']

# Making the website believe that you are accessing it using a Mozilla browser
for url in urls:
    req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    webpage = urlopen(req).read()

# Creating a BeautifulSoup object of the HTML page for easy extraction of data.
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')
html = soup.prettify('utf-8')
company_json = {}
other_details = {}

for h1 in soup.findAll('h1'):
    company_json['TICKER'] = h1.text.strip()
for span in soup.findAll('span',attrs={'class': 'Trsdu(0.3s) Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(b)'}):
    company_json['PRESENT_VALUE'] = span.text.strip()
for div in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'D(ib) Va(t)'}):
    for span in div.findAll('span', recursive=False):
        company_json['PRESENT_GROWTH'] = span.text.strip()
for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'PREV_CLOSE-value'}):
    for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
        other_details['PREV_CLOSE'] = span.text.strip()
for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'OPEN-value'}):
    for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
        other_details['OPEN'] = span.text.strip()
for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'BID-value'}):
    for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
        other_details['BID'] = span.text.strip()
for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'ASK-value'}):
    for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
        other_details['ASK'] = span.text.strip()
for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'DAYS_RANGE-value'}):
    for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
        other_details['DAYS_RANGE'] = span.text.strip()
for td in soup.findAll('td',attrs={'data-test': 'FIFTY_TWO_WK_RANGE-value'}):
    for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
        other_details['FIFTY_TWO_WK_RANGE'] = span.text.strip()
for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'TD_VOLUME-value'}):
    for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
        other_details['TD_VOLUME'] = span.text.strip()
for td in soup.findAll('td',attrs={'data-test': 'AVERAGE_VOLUME_3MONTH-value'}):
    for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
        other_details['AVERAGE_VOLUME_3MONTH'] = span.text.strip()
for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'MARKET_CAP-value'}):
    for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
        other_details['MARKET_CAP'] = span.text.strip()
for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'BETA_3Y-value'}):
    for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
        other_details['BETA_3Y'] = span.text.strip()
for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'PE_RATIO-value'}):
    for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
        other_details['PE_RATIO'] = span.text.strip()
for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'EPS_RATIO-value'}):
    for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
        other_details['EPS_RATIO'] = span.text.strip()
for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'EARNINGS_DATE-value'}):
    other_details['EARNINGS_DATE'] = []
    for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
        other_details['EARNINGS_DATE'].append(span.text.strip())
for td in soup.findAll('td',attrs={'data-test': 'DIVIDEND_AND_YIELD-value'}):
    other_details['DIVIDEND_AND_YIELD'] = td.text.strip()
for td in soup.findAll('td',attrs={'data-test': 'EX_DIVIDEND_DATE-value'}):
    for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
        other_details['EX_DIVIDEND_DATE'] = span.text.strip()
for td in soup.findAll('td',attrs={'data-test': 'ONE_YEAR_TARGET_PRICE-value' }):
    for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
        other_details['ONE_YEAR_TARGET_PRICE'] = span.text.strip()
other_details['DATE'] = str(datetime.datetime.now())
company_json['OTHER_DETAILS'] = other_details
with open('dax30_kpis.json', 'a') as outfile:
    json.dump(company_json, outfile, indent=4)
print company_json

print '----------Extraction of data is complete. Check json file.----------'
```

Comment: your indentation seems to be wrong from line `req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})` onwards all the code should be indented. Can you edit your code with the correct formatting?

Comment: Hi Simas, thanks for your answer. Somehow I am now just getting the data from the second link. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: It's because the code under your `for loop` have to be indented as per python standards.

Comment: @Valentino check my answer. I was pretty certain that was your problem but had to wait until you corrected your indentation ~

Comment: Move everything inside the loop.  The requests are made synchronously.

Comment: Ok I got it! :) i just had to format the whole code after the for loop. Thanks a lot guys you are awesome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your indentation seems to be wrong:

```
# Making the website believe that you are accessing it using a Mozilla browser
for url in urls:
    req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    webpage = urlopen(req).read()
# Creating a BeautifulSoup object of the HTML page for easy extraction of data.
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')
# ... rest of the code
```

should be

```
# Making the website believe that you are accessing it using a Mozilla browser
for url in urls:
    req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    webpage = urlopen(req).read()
    # Creating a BeautifulSoup object of the HTML page for easy extraction of data.
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')
# ... rest of the code
```

This change is necessary because you are calling all the urls in the loop and save them in a single variable. Your implementation thus ends up overwriting all the scraped websites and only processes the result returned by the last url.

You need to put all of your processing until

```
#... website processing code
with open('dax30_kpis.json', 'a') as outfile:
    json.dump(company_json, outfile, indent=4)
```

into the `for` loop as:

```
###code before###
# Making the website believe that you are accessing it using a Mozilla browser
for url in urls:
    req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    webpage = urlopen(req).read()

    # Creating a BeautifulSoup object of the HTML page for easy extraction of data.
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')
    html = soup.prettify('utf-8')
    company_json = {}
    other_details = {}

    for h1 in soup.findAll('h1'):
        company_json['TICKER'] = h1.text.strip()
    for span in soup.findAll('span',attrs={'class': 'Trsdu(0.3s) Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(b)'}):
        company_json['PRESENT_VALUE'] = span.text.strip()
    for div in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'D(ib) Va(t)'}):
        for span in div.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            company_json['PRESENT_GROWTH'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'PREV_CLOSE-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            other_details['PREV_CLOSE'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'OPEN-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            other_details['OPEN'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'BID-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            other_details['BID'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'ASK-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            other_details['ASK'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'DAYS_RANGE-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            other_details['DAYS_RANGE'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td',attrs={'data-test': 'FIFTY_TWO_WK_RANGE-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            other_details['FIFTY_TWO_WK_RANGE'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'TD_VOLUME-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            other_details['TD_VOLUME'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td',attrs={'data-test': 'AVERAGE_VOLUME_3MONTH-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            other_details['AVERAGE_VOLUME_3MONTH'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'MARKET_CAP-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            other_details['MARKET_CAP'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'BETA_3Y-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            other_details['BETA_3Y'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'PE_RATIO-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            other_details['PE_RATIO'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'EPS_RATIO-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            other_details['EPS_RATIO'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-test': 'EARNINGS_DATE-value'}):
        other_details['EARNINGS_DATE'] = []
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            other_details['EARNINGS_DATE'].append(span.text.strip())
    for td in soup.findAll('td',attrs={'data-test': 'DIVIDEND_AND_YIELD-value'}):
        other_details['DIVIDEND_AND_YIELD'] = td.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td',attrs={'data-test': 'EX_DIVIDEND_DATE-value'}):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            other_details['EX_DIVIDEND_DATE'] = span.text.strip()
    for td in soup.findAll('td',attrs={'data-test': 'ONE_YEAR_TARGET_PRICE-value' }):
        for span in td.findAll('span', recursive=False):
            other_details['ONE_YEAR_TARGET_PRICE'] = span.text.strip()
    other_details['DATE'] = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    company_json['OTHER_DETAILS'] = other_details
    with open('dax30_kpis.json', 'a') as outfile:
        json.dump(company_json, outfile, indent=4)
    print company_json
### Code after ###
```